# React Form Not Displaying in Browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I'm not sure why the form's not displaying in the browser.

The formComponentDict variable isn't displaying any of the form steps. What am I missing?
Any help is appreactiated. Thanks

```
const formComponentDict = {
  1: () => (
    <FormPersonalDetails
      nextStep={this.nextStep}
      handleChange={this.handleChange}
      values={values}
    />
  ),
  2: () => (
    <FormBusinessDetails
      nextStep={this.nextStep}
      prevStep={this.prevStep}
      handleChange={this.handleChange}
      values={values}
    />
  ),
  3: () => (
    <FormProductDetails
      nextStep={this.nextStep}
      prevStep={this.prevStep}
      handleChange={this.handleChange}
      values={values}
    />
  ),
  4: () => (
    <FormConfirmation
      nextStep={this.nextStep}
      prevStep={this.prevStep}
      values={values}
    />
  ),
  5: () => <FormSubmission />,
};

return formComponentDict[step] ? (
  formComponentDict[step]
) : (
  <p>Invalid Form</p>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're storing each component as a function which returns the component in `formComponentDict`, your component returns a function which returns a component (`FormBusinessDetails`, `FormPersonalDetails` ...) when it should be returning the component (`FormBusinessDetails`, `FormPersonalDetails` ...) itself. Try changing `formComponentDict` like below:

```
const formComponentDict = {
  1: (
    <FormPersonalDetails
      nextStep={this.nextStep}
      handleChange={this.handleChange}
      values={values}
    />
  ),
  2: (
    <FormBusinessDetails
      nextStep={this.nextStep}
      prevStep={this.prevStep}
      handleChange={this.handleChange}
      values={values}
    />
  ),
  3: (
    <FormProductDetails
      nextStep={this.nextStep}
      prevStep={this.prevStep}
      handleChange={this.handleChange}
      values={values}
    />
  ),
  4: (
    <FormConfirmation
      nextStep={this.nextStep}
      prevStep={this.prevStep}
      values={values}
    />
  ),
  5: <FormSubmission />,
};
```

Comment: That fixed it. Appreciate the help